# Rotate a face in JavaScript (Node.js 10)

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, math, face-recognition

I am following a face recognition algorithm but I need to rotate all faces to align them vertically to its rectangle.

The face rectangle is not rotated (its angle is 0) and it contains the full face that has been recognised. The face sometimes is rotated "faceAngle" degrees, so what I have implement is a function that rotate it (the face) "-faceAngle" degrees with the center of the face rectangle as pivot point (the point of reference).

Pd: The face is identified by 20 landmarks.

This is how the face rectangle looks like: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/cognitive-services/face/images/face.detection.jpg

Here is my code:

```
  function rotateFace(face) {
      /*
        This function rotate the face to the rectangle based on the head pose attributes
      */

      // Get the face information
      const { faceRectangle, faceLandmarks, faceAttributes } = face;

      // Head pose's roll value acts directly as the face angle.
      const faceAngle = faceAttributes.headPose.roll; // In degrees

      // The pivot point will be the center of the face rectangle
      const pivotPoint = {
        x: faceRectangle.width / 2,
        y: faceRectangle.height / 2,
      };

      // Rotate each face landmark '-faceAngle' degrees
      const rotatedLandmarks = {};
      for (const [landMark, point] of Object.entries(faceLandmarks)) {
        // Rotate the point and save it in the new rotated landMarks object
        rotatedLandmarks[landMark] = rotatePoint(pivotPoint, point, -faceAngle);
      }

      // Return the rotated face
      return { ...face, faceLandmarks: rotatedLandmarks };

      function rotatePoint(pivotPoint, point, angle) {
        const { x: px, y: py } = pivotPoint;
        const { x, y } = point;

        var radians = (Math.PI / 180) * angle,
          cos = Math.cos(radians),
          sin = Math.sin(radians),
          nx = cos * (x - px) + sin * (y - py) + px,
          ny = cos * (y - py) - sin * (x - px) + py;

        return { x: nx, y: ny };
      }
  }
```

The problem I am having is that, sometimes, some parts of the rotated face are outside the face rectangle... Does anybody knows what I am doing bad in my algorithm? Or any ideas how to make this easier?

I think the pivot point shouldn't be the one I choosed but it makes sense for my mind...

Thank you.

### EXAMPLE

For this photo https://scstylecaster.files.wordpress.com/2017/03/emma-watson-1.jpg

I get this face rectangle:

```
faceRectangle: {
   top: 90,
   left: 309,
   width: 510,
   height: 510 
}
```

So the relative-to-rectangle face landmarks should be at the range [0, 510] for the X axis, and [0, 510] for the Y axis

But that I get is:

```
{
  "eyebrowRightInner": { "x": 257.16357408506883, "y": 37.89185642687593 },
  "underLipTop": { "y": 306.6951578378977, "x": 326.5280833858301 },
  "mouthRight": { "x": 413.55677612276986, "y": 257.5870460792551 },
  "eyebrowLeftInner": { "y": 67.10580836435113, "x": 168.71276847994784 },
  "noseTip": { "y": 206.5354065431846, "x": 289.9445594907593 },
  "noseRootLeft": { "y": 112.52684633627678, "x": 204.9452029765821 },
  "noseRightAlarTop": { "x": 311.41755898744964, "y": 159.77912041377596 },
  "pupilRight": { "x": 315.13546073674706, "y": 48.933158797745136 },
  "pupilLeft": { "x": 106.47397872844112, "y": 137.8818851860268 },
  "upperLipTop": { "y": 280.73055222306243, "x": 312.3126250651826 },
  "eyeRightOuter": { "y": 37.448988851675836, "x": 371.07188751438275 },
  "eyebrowRightOuter": { "y": -16.27549040986449, "x": 413.1946880869507 }, // <------------------ error
  "eyeLeftOuter": { "y": 154.79417336302782, "x": 82.3579154382175 },
  "upperLipBottom": { "y": 302.33231999033967, "x": 324.86506026034 },
  "noseLeftAlarOutTip": { "y": 244.55778079547065, "x": 220.11663487446322 },
  "noseLeftAlarTop": { "x": 220.08119281608163, "y": 200.35236547267908 },
  "eyeLeftBottom": { "y": 154.39022448200217, "x": 120.07378511268632 },
  "noseRightAlarOutTip": { "x": 350.8688839396136, "y": 182.97767553082463 },
  "eyebrowLeftOuter": { "x": 12.151092571862137, "y": 146.8442033623165 },
  "eyeRightBottom": { "x": 337.62439624997774, "y": 64.52859978162735 },
  "eyeLeftTop": { "y": 124.33543005444903, "x": 103.84081459224478 },
  "underLipBottom": { "y": 332.64619899450827, "x": 341.8614934073455 },
  "noseRootRight": { "y": 86.3352712525471, "x": 268.4137100854889 },
  "eyeLeftInner": { "x": 154.06657444677165, "y": 128.0195917006581 },
  "eyeRightInner": { "x": 294.24199118290403, "y": 71.94256839474764 },
  "eyeRightTop": { "x": 320.5652039630463, "y": 34.94002160494745 },
  "mouthLeft": { "y": 346.12770549550777, "x": 220.09672435462016 }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an image where you have an example of "sometimes, some parts of the rotated are outside the rectangle". What are we talking about, a few pixels or a lot? Please provide input values and example output, then someone could easier help you.

Comment: It seems that I am inverting the face...

Comment: Mh, I would like to help you hunt down the bug, but I cannot reproduce your issue (because of having no code setup at all). Is there a possibility you could upload your setup/code on GitHub? Only the relevant stuff. Also I highly suggest moving out the  `rotatePoint` function out of the `rotateFace` function. You would define the function every time the rotatePoint is called.

Comment: So, if I only call rotateFace one time and inside it I call rotatePoint 20 times, the function "rotatePoint" will be redefined 20 times??!! Okey, I will try to reproduce an example.

Comment: No. If any one would call your `rotateFace` function multiple times (for example on multiple images, like 1.000.000 images), then rotatePoint would be redefined multiple times :)

Comment: I have found the error... It was that the LandMarks were relative-to-image and not relative -to-rectangle, so I had to change them before rotating because the pivot point was relative-to-rectangle.

Comment: Please answer to your own question with the solution. If anyone has a similar problem he would have some help to fix his bug, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the error... It was that the LandMarks were relative-to-image and not relative -to-rectangle, so I had to change them before rotating because the pivot point was relative-to-rectangle.

Just make sure you get the position of each landmark relative to the rectangle before rotating it. Other solution would be to take the center of the rectangle but relative-to-image instead of relative-to-rectangle, and use the original (relative-to-image) landmarks.